# Alternate to singleton in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, architecture, singleton

Working as software architecture many years i hate to use singletons in cases where i could avoid them. But having to make some task for android application i encounter case when the singleton seems to be the only one alternative. May be someone could propose something else?

The task is to make an UI wizard for creating some new entity (trip description in my case). Entity is complex and requires several pages to fulfill all its data.

Wizard is organized as several fragments pushed to back stack one after one as users go to next page. But all fragments should work with one instance of editing entity. And this entity should stay alive when activity recreated (after rotation or in other cases). If the page was only one i could just save/restore entity in onSaveInstanceState. But if i will do so in all fragments of my wizard all fragments will hold its own instances of entity (because all of them save it and then restore). And wizard will work wrong (for example when you navigate back to previous pages).

For more pain, let's say that activity that holds this fragments should not know anything about this specific wizard and i will not put any code specific to this wizard to activity. Disabling activity is also not an option in my case.

So in this situation, the obvious solution is to create the singleton that holds my editing entity. And made all of the wizard fragments works with this singleton. 90% of my programmers will choose such solution without any doubt. But my brain protests against it. Why i should make the entity singleton when it is not a singleton by its nature???

So if someone could suggest something different i would be very appreciated.

Comment: 'service' in terms of android?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have following:

- Application class;
- WizardManager;
- SomeWizardDataEntity;

You can create WizardManager in Application class and use this it with data entity for your wizard flow, i.e:

```
//BaseFragment:
WizardManager manager = getApplication().getWizardManager();
SomeWizardDataEntity entity = manager.getWizardEntity();

//Fragment1:
entity.addSomeData();

//Fragment2:
entity.addSomeData2();

//Fragment3:
entity.addSomeData3();

//Fragment4:
entity.addSomeData4();
manager.wizardFlowFinihed();
```

So you will have non-singleton instance of WizardManager that will live until Application class is alive.

Then you can write some test moking this entity, i.e.:

```
@Mock
WizardManager mWizardManager;

//start some fragment

verify(entity, times(1)).addSomeData();
verify(manager, times(1)).wizardFlowFinihed();
```